# "Upliftment of poor" vs. "upliftment of the poor"

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles

> The Government has decided to introduce the new scheme for the upliftment of poor.

Should it be "of the poor" or not?

Comment: Without the definite article, *poor* does not refer to anything in particular, certainly not *the poor people* as should be.

Comment: _Upliftment_? How about _"...for uplifting the poor."_ (I'm not going down the _no-such-word_ road, but it does seem rare or unusual at best).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, *the poor* is correct.

The reason is that *poor* on its own is an adjective, which invites the question "poor what?". To turn it definitively into a noun it needs to be *the poor*.

Having said that, I did find a quote where just *poor* is used, in the [Hindustan Times](http://www.hindustantimes.com/India-news/NewDelhi/Delhi-s-irony-Urban-Poverty/Article1-837141.aspx):

> The Delhi government does not have an estimate of the number of poor living in the metropolis.

This indicates that it may be an acceptable Indian-English idiom.

As an aside, *upliftment* is awkward. *Uplift* is better; *improvement* or *betterment* better still.

Comment: [The number of poor](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+number+of+poor+in%2C+the+number+of+the+poor+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is acceptable everywhere, I'd say.

Comment: Yes, because it implies 'people' - the number of poor people, which is evidently correct.

Comment: However @GuyF-W, "... for the upliftment of poor." definitely doesn't work in BrEng. *Poor* is an uncountable noun there, so it needs an article or to be turned into an adjective.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that *upliftment* is an awkward word (espoused by Indian English in particular?). Agreed, *betterment* is much better.

Comment: *for uplift of the poor* or *for uplifting the poor* are OK, but  with *improve* or *better* you need something more: the scheme does not improve or better the poor, but their condition.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes,there is no such word "upliftment" but for now you can consider it as "betterment".Then Should it be "of the poor" or not?

Comment: @Sudhir  "of the poor" is fine; I'm saying you should not write "betterment of the poor" because you are not proposing to make the poor better -- you are proposing to make the *lives* of the poor better, or the *lot* of the poor, or their *living conditions*, or whatever.

Comment: @MattЭллен Someone once mentioned something about statistics proving anything, I think. "Of the poor" is [a *lot* more acceptable](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+poor+in%2Cof+the+poor+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than "of poor".

Comment: I've seen typos even on BBC site, doubt that Hindustan Times is an exception (i.e. not sure this is acceptable in Indian English either)